# Update combobox/listbox datasources from backgroundworker called voids

Tags: wpf, controls, datasource, backgroundworker

I have about 5 voids that query the database and then set the datasource of some controls. As the UI was not frozen while updating the controls, I'm using a BackGroundWorker. Is there a way I can use the same voids to update the controls? just calling them from the DoWork... (it crashs when It tries to update the datasources with the void that the DoWork called).

Thanks Allon. Great reply! I need to get better basis for my WPF coding.. :S this is what I did..

```
private void UpdateStates(Boolean UpdateLeft, Boolean UpdateRight)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        States.State State = new States.State();

        if (UpdateRight == true)
        {
            cState.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ds = State.StatesTable();
                cState.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                cState.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();
                cState.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
            });
        }
      }
```

Is this ok? it tells me that it cant convert lambda on system.delegate type because it is not a delegated type.. any ideas? I'm googling to get but you help will be great for me! Thanks!

Comment: Use Async programming instead of BackgroundWorker for that

Comment: I've never hear methods being called 'voids', unless I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interact with a WPF controls from a background thread, you must use their dispatcher to marshal the call to the UI thread. So instead of accessing the control directly:

```
var data = LoadAHugeDataset()
myControl.DataContext = data;
```

Use the control's Dispatcher to run the code:

```
var data = LoadAHugeDataset()
myControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { myControl.DataContext = data; });
```

Comment: @Max: To solve your issue you must add a reference to `System.Windows.Presentation.dll` and add the `using System.Windows.Threading` directive at the top of the file to be able to use that extension method.

Comment: It still gives the same error.. "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: @Max: Are you using a version of .NET older than 3.5 SP1? If you're using a non-SP1 version of .NET 3.5, then cast the lambda to an Action delegate (`.Invoke((Action)() => ...)`). If you're using .NET 3.0, the answer depends on what version of Visual Studio you're using.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 with the Framework 4 and WPF... so weird.. the method is called by the DoWork event of a BackGroundWorker.. I've been googling but cant fix it!

Comment: @Max: The method I'm using is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647495.aspx) extension method for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) class. If you add the assembly reference and the `using` directive it should work.